# Difference between Sql Server 2000, 2005 and 2008

Tags: sql-server

HI All

Can any one have tabular info regarding the difference between Sql Server 2000, 2005 and 2008

Thanks

Kishh

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://sanjeevas.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!141DB013CCB3E7EA!172.entry) is one.

Comment: Thanks Oded. But i am looking for more comparison.

Comment: @Kishh - perhaps you need to add detail to your question then, about _what_ is important to you in such a comparison.

Comment: @Kishh - then edit your question, add this piece of information to it and explain _exactly_ what comparison you need. Programmer point of view can be - SQL programmer, .NET programmer, C programmer... Are you talking about CLR in SQL Server? Just about connectivity? What exactly?

Comment: @Kishh - Last time I say this. _Edit_ the question. Make your intentions clearer.

Comment: I need difference between the Sql Server 2000, 2005 and 2008 in a tabular format, so that any developer can understand that:)